# How to navigate to page when on resume is called in app.xaml.cs for mvvm in xamarin forms app

Tags: xamarin.forms, navigation, prism

I have an issue with navigation. When I click home screen button of device and get back to app I get app homescreen instead of pin page. Ideally it should show pin page and its working fine with back button of device.
OnStart() method has navigationasync but the same is not working with OnResume() method.
Do I have to go to each of the Platform project cs file and add the navigation there like for Android OnRestart()/OnResume() method?
If anyone knows the solution please let me know

Answer (score 1):

Most commonly when writing your Xamarin Application with Prism you will have something like:

```
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    NavigationService.NavigateAsync("SomePage");
}
```

OnInitialized is called each time the App's ctor is invoked. This is an important consideration here because this means that any time that the native platform tombstones the app in the background or otherwise refreshes the app by calling OnCreate in your MainActivity or FinishedLaunching in your AppDelegate, then OnInitialized will be invoked resetting your App's Navigation stack to `SomePage`.

You can however override the OnStart/OnResume in PrismApplication and use whatever business logic you need to determine where to navigate and how you might want to restore your application.

```
public override void OnStart()
{
    NavigationService.NavigateAsync("MainPage");
}

public override void OnResume()
{
    if(someCondition)
    {
        NavigationService.NavigateAsync("SomePage");
    }
    else
    {
        NavigationService.NavigateAsync("AnotherPage");
    }
}
```